# Transactionally SCPing to multiple servers in python

Tags: python, linux, scp

I need to SCP the same file to multiple servers, transactionally. It will overwrite the previous version of the file. I need to guarantee that every server has the new file, or every server has the old file. It is acceptable for the servers to appear to be in an intermediate state temporarily, as long as it ends in consistent state.

Is there a good library for this in python? I have been googling around, and most transactional libraries seem to be designed with databases in mind.

If there isn't what is a good way to go about this?

Added: I should say "as transactional as possible". I recognise that the situation make true transactionality difficult, but the goal is to get as close as possible, and scream for the sysadmin if they go south anyway.

Comment: Is python usage a requirement? Can't you use, say, `git`, or other suitable tools?

Comment: There has been some speculation about whether we can use git on the satellite servers for things like this. But whether we use git or scp, we must drive it from a django web app on the core server (the picture of our system presented here is simplified)

Answer (score 2):

Real transactions are probably best handled with databases that reach the replication level that you need

While their is probably not something that will magically handle this for you, you can follow some best practices and end up with OK results. I don't really know where to start but let's try some of these:

- Paramiko can be used to handle the mechanics of an ssh session from python if that is important to you.
- Making files somewhat atomic is typically handled by copying your new file to the same storage subsystem and then renaming it. Linux allows this to be atomic using the renameat system call.
- Within python you can have a try except finally block such that at least your running application is aware of what the state of things are.
- Messaging Queues (like zeroMQ) may help in being able to reliably send messages between computers.
- None of this really addresses what happens when actual problems occur which is why if you want real transactions use a database.

Comment: Thanks, I have Paramiko already. And it really does have to be files copied by scp. Transactional-ish should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

1) copy file to all servers, into a temporary path on the same drive as the final location. If this fails just restart it.

2) across all servers, move the file from temp path into the final path. On Linux and probably other OSes, moving files on a single drive is fast, durable, and probably atomic.

This isn't atomic, but #2 is fast and durable. You're guaranteed each server will have either the old file, or the new file, but not a combination.